# Was Khavtasi a real person?

Tags: georgian-language, lasha-bugadze, the-literature-express

In *The Literature Express*, the narrator was asked by the Ministry of Culture to go on the Literature Express only after Khavtasi, a poet who is described as "senile", refused to go.

Is Khavtasi a real poet (or even based on a real person)? Also, is this likely a first name or a surname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Literature Express was a novel by Lasha Bugadze, and not a true story.

A couple of links about the above:

- [The Literature Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Literature_Express) (Wikipedia),
- [The Literature Express. Author: Lasha Bugadze](https://dublinliteraryaward.ie/books/the-literature-express/), DUBLIN Literary Award, Z014.
- [The Literature Express /by Lasha Bugadze/](http://bookplatform.org/en/activities/830-the-literature-express.html), Book Platform (no date).

And Khavtasi seems to be a surname. Apart from the page [Khavtasia Surname](https://forebears.io/surnames/khavtasia) on Forbears.io, if we search on LinkedIn for Khavtasi, all the profiles with this show it as a surname.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you please replace the bare URLs with meaningful linktext? In other words, make sure that the title of the target page is used as linktext instead of the URL itself? (See [Links and Hypertext](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text#text) for background.)